# Dictionary output on one line

Tags: python, python-3.3

I'm a beginner learning Python 3.3 through http://GrokLearning.com

My objective is to write a Word2SMS program. The program tells the user which "number buttons" to press on basic cell phones (non-smartphones) in order to spell out a given word. The input word will be given in all uppercase letters - no numbers or punctuation. Assume the phone can perfectly predict the word given corresponding number input from the user.

**Sample goal output:**

```
> GROK
4765
```

---

**My code:**

```
KEYPAD = {'A': '2', 'B': '2', 'C': '2', 'D': '3', 'E': '3', 'F': '3', 'G': '4', 'H': '4', 'I': '4', 'J': '5', 'K': '5', 'L': '5', 'M': '6', 'N': '6', 'O': '6', 'P': '7', 'Q': '7', 'R': '7', 'S': '7', 'T': '8', 'U': '8', 'V': '8', 'W': '9', 'X': '9', 'Y': '9', 'Z': '9'}
word = input("Enter word: ")
for key in word:
    print(KEYPAD[key], end='')
```

---

**The result:**

My code returns the same digits, all on one line, with no whitespace between the digits, just as I want. However, I receive this notification: ***Your output is missing a trailing newline character.***

[image: Missing trailing newline character]

I've tried adding `'\n'` to add a new line at the end; this gives me *unexpected character after line continuation character* SyntaxError.

Adding `' '` at the end results in one digit per line.

---

For reference, I have gone through all of the free modules, but not any of the paid ones. Since my knowledge is limited, please explain your answer in simple terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to print out one newline after you process the input string:

```
KEYPAD = {'A': '2', 'B': '2', 'C': '2', 'D': '3', 'E': '3', 'F': '3', 'G': '4', 'H': '4', 'I': '4', 'J': '5', 'K': '5', 'L': '5', 'M': '6', 'N': '6', 'O': '6', 'P': '7', 'Q': '7', 'R': '7', 'S': '7', 'T': '8', 'U': '8', 'V': '8', 'W': '9', 'X': '9', 'Y': '9', 'Z': '9'}
word = input("Enter word: ")
for key in word:
    print(KEYPAD[key], end='') #<-- this line suppresses the newline output
print() #<-- this adds the required newline at the end of all the characters
```

Comment: Thank you for such a simple fix!
It makes sense to a beginner like me.

Comment: @Styna, glad it helped. Because you wrote a detailed and clear question it made it much easier to help you find a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

For an even shorter solution:

```
KEYPAD = {'A': '2', 'B': '2', 'C': '2', 'D': '3', 'E': '3', 'F': '3', 'G': '4', 'H': '4', 'I': '4', 'J': '5', 'K': '5', 'L': '5', 'M': '6', 'N': '6', 'O': '6', 'P': '7', 'Q': '7', 'R': '7', 'S': '7', 'T': '8', 'U': '8', 'V': '8', 'W': '9', 'X': '9', 'Y': '9', 'Z': '9'}
word = input("Enter word: ")
print(''.join([KEYPAD[k] for k in word])) # This will join all the buttons together and print with an automatic newline
```

*By the way your error "unexpected character after line continuation character SyntaxError." means that you put the `\n` outside of quotes.  `\` outside of quotes means continued on the next line so there should not be any text other than newline after it.*

Comment: Thank you for showing me this condensed version. By the way, I did try `\n` both inside and outside of the closing parenthesis and I received an error both times.